# How to manually throw a 503 error on scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping Amazon, and I want to be able to throw a 503 error anytime I receive a captcha from the website. This would allow this webpage to be retried later. I can already detect if there is a captcha on the page, I just need to be able to throw the 503 error to retry it later. Below is the ideal way I would be able to accomplish my goal.

```
 if response.css('#captchacharacters').extract()[0]:
     # Insert code to throw an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Downloadermiddleware like below,

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware

class TutorialDownloaderMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # test for captcha page
        if response.css('#captchacharacters').extract()[0]:
            reason = 'capcha'
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
        return response
```

Don't forget to add it in the settings,

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'tutorial.middlewares.TutorialDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

It will redirect and retry.

Comment: What does the number after the colon do in the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES section?

Comment: Method of each middleware will be invoked in decreasing order. Check this out.https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-middlewares-base